# How to get fields of related object in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, ui-record-api

Currently I'm able to fetch all required fields from Opportunity as shown below:

```
import STAGE from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.StageName';
```

Similarly I need to fetch the Account fields which is linked to current opportunity but it is not working. This what I've tried:

```
import OPP_ACCOUNT_MY_CUSTOM_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.AccountId__r.MyCustomField__c';
```

And I'm using getRecord() to fetch the Opportunity record as shown below:

```
const fields = [STAGE, OPP_ACCOUNT_MY_CUSTOM_FIELD ];   
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })oppId;
```

Trying to access the data with getFieldValue() as shown below:

```
let myCustomField = getFieldValue(data, OPP_ACCOUNT_MY_CUSTOM_FIELD );
```

What should be changed in the import to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
import OPP_ACCOUNT_MY_CUSTOM_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.AccountId__r.MyCustomField__c';
```

To

```
import OPP_ACCOUNT_MY_CUSTOM_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Account.MyCustomField__c';
```

Comment: You should explain why this fixes the issue. Standard lookups are `SomethingId` and the relationship is then just `Something` while custom lookups are `Something__c` and the relationship is `Something__r`.

Comment: I do not believe `getRecord` can access related object fields directly either.